# Rename file with DropZoneJS when upload succesfull

Tags: dropzone.js

I've been trying all answer founding in the net and that never work, i would like that the file who is save in the PDF folder and in the database behind a choose name while uploading.

This is my code :[index.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfVHG.png)

[upload.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq1fc.png)

Comment: Please do not post code as an image. Try to come up with a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can be posted as a text snippet. See [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202815/how-should-i-show-lengthy-code-on-stack-overflow) for guidelines on posting long code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

INDEX.PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="widht=device-widht, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Glisser-deposer </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dropzone.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="header">
        <h1> Glisser-deposer les fichiers de telechargement<br> </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <form class="dropzone" id="file_upload"></form>
        <button id="upload_btn">telechargement</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dropzone.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropzone").dropzone({
    renameFilename: function (filename) {
        return new Date().getTime() + '_' + filename;
    }
    });
    });

 var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#file_upload", { 
    
    url: "upload.php", 
    parallelUploads: 3,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    acceptedFiles: '.pdf',      
    clickable: true,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
     renameFilename: function (filename) {
    name  = new Date().getTime() + '-' + filename;
    return name;
},  
    
    success: function(file,response){
     if(response == 'true'){
     
      $('#content .message').hide();
      $('#content').append('<div classe="message success">Fichier Telecharger avec 
   succes.</div>');
     }else{
      $('#content').append('<div classe="message error">Le fichier ne peux etre 
  telecharger.</div>');
    }
  } 
});     
    
$('#upload_btn').click(function(){
    myDropzone.processQueue();
    });
    
    
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

UPLOAD.PHP :

```
<?php

/* Créer une connexion*/
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","intranet"); // ("nom d'hôte", "nom 
d'utilisateur", "mot de passe", " nom de la base")

/* Vérifier la connexion*/
 if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if($_FILES['file']['name'] != ''){

    $file_names = '';

    $total = count($_FILES['file']['name']);

    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i]; // Obtenez le nom du fichier 
téléchargé.
        $extension = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION); //Obtenez l'extension du 
fichier téléchargé
    
        $valid_extensions = array('pdf','.txt');
    
        if(in_array($extension, $valid_extensions)){ // vérifier si le fichier de 
téléchargement est un fichier pdf valide.
            $new_name = rand() . ".". $extension;
            $path = "PDF/" . $new_name;
        
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $path);
        
             $file_names .= $new_name . " , ";
        }else{
            echo 'false';
        }
    }

    // Enregistrer le nom des fichiers téléchargées dans la base de données
    $sql = "INSERT INTO fichier VALUES('{$file_names}')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
        echo 'true';
    }else{
        echo 'false';
    }
}


?>
```